# I want to delete H2 Database completely

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I want about to delete the H2 database from the running spring boot.

Instead of simply deleting the *.mv.db file as a File class, we found the library provided by h2. However, I deleted the file, but the data in the DB remains the same. It can even be Inserted, and ican continue to use it as if i have a file.

The code I used is as follows.

```
String datasource_nm = "test";
String path = "/home/java/";
DeleteDbFiles.execute(path, datasource_nm, true);
```

This code allows me to delete the *.mv.db file in the h2 database. However, I think this code itself deletes the file, but it does not completely delete it.

If the running DB is deleted, you can still perform the Select, Insert, Update, and Delete statements.

Since all existing DB data disappears only after a reboot, it seems that they were using it as in-memory even if they didn't have a file.

Is there a way to remove the file completely as well as the file even if I delete it while running?

Comment: If you delete it while running the data is still in memory. What is it you are trying to do anyway? If you don't want the data persisted don't use a file store but regular in-memory store.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JPA (you didn't mention it in the text, but added a tag [jpa]), you have to see the database accessed by a transparent cache. You must not tamper with the underlying database files in that case.

To circumvent this, you would have to create your own management layer over the JPA access where you can "shut it off" - this means that you would have to ensure that each `EntityManager` will stop working, etc. Then you can "stop" the database and delete the file.

But you cannot use Spring Boot's built in tools for database access then.

Comment: Sure you can. You just need to write a component that runs last when the application does a shutdown to remove the files. But using a file and cleaning up afterwards is a bit strange why not use an in-memory version then.

Comment: OP didn't mention that DB file should be deleted just on shutdown. It looked more like "in the middle of nowhere" to me, but of course if it's at the end of the application lifetime you are right, @M.Deinum